# VB.net: Arrays and DataType difference

Tags: vb.net, arrays

This is just a quick question:

Are there any difference between

```
dim b as byte()
```

to

```
dim b() as byte
```

does this also work for string, integers ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same. However, note the following differences:

```
Dim b As Byte()           ' Declares a variable of type byte array, initialized to Nothing
Dim b() As Byte           ' Declares a variable of type byte array, initialized to Nothing 
Dim b As New Byte()       ' Creates a new, single byte with value 0
Dim b = New Byte()        ' Creates a new, single byte with value 0
Dim b = New Byte() {}     ' Creates a new byte array with zero elements
Dim b = New Byte() {1, 2} ' Creates a new byte array with two elements
```

This is a bit confusing, since in VB `T()` can mean (a) a constructor call of Type `T` with no parameters and (b) an array of `T`.

Comment: I am of the opinion that all examples be Option Strict On friendly.  Not encouraging others to be explicit in their declarations is a bad habit, that sooner or later causes problems.

Comment: is the first two examples and dim b = new byte () {} the same? Sorry, I find that confusing.

Comment: @dbasnett: The examples *are* compatible with Option Strict On. (And I agree with your point.)

Comment: @MrA: No: The first two examples initialize the variable to `Nothing`, whereas `New Byte() {}` creates a zero-element array. That's something different.

Comment: @Heinzi - the last two example fail with Strict On, or they do when I paste them into my IDE.

Comment: @dbasnett: They fail only if you have [`Option Infer Off`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx).  ;-) With Option Infer On, `b` is correctly inferred as `Byte`.

Comment: Which I do.  Strict On, Infer Off, Explicit On is such a habit that I forget the interaction.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no difference in this case. And it's the same for any type of array (Integer, String, or any other class).

It would only make a difference if you'd want to specify the array length. This is valid syntax:

```
Dim b(5) As Byte
```

While this is NOT valid:

```
Dim b As Byte(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. The later syntax is more for backwards compatibility. Before .Net, you would define an array variable of type byte. In .Net, however, it is a variable of type byte array. Both syntax will work for any type.